# Allocating memory and filling the structure elements of a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have defined the structure in a separate header file and I have included that header file in my main file.

The header file consists of a structure like this:

```
 typedef struct
 {
 char name[32];
 unsigned int a;
 unsigned int b;
 NUMBER_ONE variable1;
 NUMBER_TWO variable2;
 }NUMBER_THREE,*PNUMBER_THREE;


typedef struct
{
unsigned int variable3;
char variable4[8];
}NUMBER_ONE,*PNUMBER_ONE;


typedef struct
{
unsigned int variable5;
char variable6[8];
}NUMBER_TWO,*PNUMBER_TWO;
```

Now in my main file I have to allocate memory for this structure and I need to fill this structure with some values, so anybody please tell me how to do this. I need to send this through socket client to the socket server.

Comment: what don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have written it in that order you present it, then the code should not even compile since the first typedef has no clue on what NUMBER_ONE or NUMBER_TWO types are.

To allocate it should just be to define a variable of given type.

```
int main()
{
NUMBER_TWO number_two_var;
number_two_var.variable5 = 10;

}
```

I would also recommend using a postfix for each typdef, for example NUMBER_TWO_T.

Edit: Postfix being _T

Comment: Initialize variables with initializers, that's what they are made for and not by assignment. Initializers have the extra feature that they set all other fields to `0`, this is an important guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

In C a `struct` is initialized by an initializer

```
NUMBER_TWO a2 = { .variable5 = 7, .variable6 = { 'a', }, };
```

the form I am giving here are so-called designated initializers that came starting with C99. Oldish C had only the equivalent

```
NUMBER_TWO a2 = { 7, { 'a' } };
```

where you have to specify the values in declaration order.

For both forms, fields that are omitted from the initializer are initialized with `0`.